# Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JavaScript object and want to get the highest value of all entries.
I have tried this:

```js
d = {
"A": [ {"value": 10}, {"value": 20}, {"value": 30} ],
"B": [ {"value": 50}, {"value": 60}, {"value": 1000} ],
}

Object.keys(d).map(
    function(k) { 
        Math.max.apply(Math, d[k].map(
            function(e) {
                console.log(value);
            }
        ))
    }
)
```

The result should be 1000.

Comment: *I have some JSON data* no you don't you have a javascript object, JSON is a different thing

Answer (score 7):

You can use spread syntax `...` in `Math.max` after you `map` and flatten the array.

```js
const d = {
  "A": [ {"value": 10}, {"value": 20}, {"value": 30} ],
  "B": [ {"value": 50}, {"value": 60}, {"value": 1000} ],
}

const max = Math.max(...[].concat(...Object.values(d)).map(({value}) => value))
console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.values`, `flatMap` and `Math.max` with spreading.

```js
const d = {"A":[{"value":10},{"value":20},{"value":30}],"B":[{"value":50},{"value":60},{"value":1000}]};
const res = Math.max(...Object.values(d).flat().flatMap(Object.values));
console.log(res);
```

Because `flat` isn't well supported (and neither is `flatMap`) you can use `reduce` as well.

```js
const d = {"A":[{"value":10},{"value":20},{"value":30}],"B":[{"value":50},{"value":60},{"value":1000}]};
const res = Math.max(...Object.values(d).map(e => e.map(Object.values)).reduce((a, c) => [].concat(...a, ...c)));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `Object.values(...).flat is not a function`

Comment: It's running perfectly in the snippet @Cid - check your browser (`flat` isn't well-supported). I'll add some better-supported variants.

Comment: I'm using Firefox Quantum 60.7.0esr (32 bits)

Comment: I'm using Safari latest. Works perfectly.

Comment: Considering official [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility) it's available on firefox since the version 62

Answer (score 0):

If you want es5 code, try this:

```
var d = {
"A": [ {"value": 10}, {"value": 20}, {"value": 30} ],
"B": [ {"value": 50}, {"value": 60}, {"value": 1000} ],
};

var results = [];
for(var key in d)
{
    d[key].forEach(function (obj){
        results.push(obj.value);
    });
}
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, results));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this by flattening the values first then sorting it in ascending order and taking the last element out of the sorted array:

```js
const data = {
  "A": [ {"value": 10}, {"value": 20}, {"value": 30 } ],
  "B": [ {"value": 50}, {"value": 60}, {"value": 1000} ],
};


const highestValue = Object.values(data)
.flatMap(x => x)
.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)
.slice(-1);

console.log(highestValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
d = {
    "A": [{ "value": 10 }, { "value": 20 }, { "value": 30 }],
    "B": [{ "value": 50 }, { "value": 60 }, { "value": 1000 }],
}


var maxValue = Math.max.apply(null,Object.keys(d).map(key => Math.max.apply(null,d[key].map(x => x.value))));

console.log(maxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *good old loop*

```js
let d = {
"A": [ {"value": 10}, {"value": 20}, {"value": 30} ],
"B": [ {"value": 50}, {"value": 60}, {"value": 1000} ],
}

let maxValue;
for (let key in d)
{
  for (let i = 0, len = d[key].length; i < len; ++i)
  {
    if (maxValue === undefined || maxValue < d[key][i].value)
      maxValue = d[key][i].value;
  }
}

console.log(maxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since neither [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) nor [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) are well supported without polyfill here is a solution with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const d = {
"A": [ {"value": 10}, {"value": 20}, {"value": 30} ],
"B": [ {"value": 50}, {"value": 60}, {"value": 1000} ],
}

let r = Math.max(...Object.values(d).reduce((r,c)=>[...r,...c]).map(x => x.value))

console.log(r)
```

The idea is to use `Object.values` to get straight to the values of the object. Then use `Array.reduce` for the flattening of the arrays and `Array.map` to extract the `value`. Then spread to `Math.max` for the final result.

Answer (score 0):

For actual JSON string, it can be done during parsing :

```js
var max = -Infinity, json = '{"A":[{"value":10},{"value":20},{"value":30}],"B":[{"value":50},{"value":60},{"value":1000}]}'

JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => max = v > max ? v : max)

console.log( max )
```

For JavaScript object :

```js
const d = { "A": [ {"value": 10}, {"value": 20}, {"value":   30 } ],
            "B": [ {"value": 50}, {"value": 60}, {"value": 1000 } ] }

console.log( Math.max(...Object.values(d).flat().map(x => x.value)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Only simply using map and reduce and chaining them together can give you the desired max value. 
I have used underscore js though, you can use simple map and reduce methods for the same.

```
var d = {
     "A": [ {"value": 10}, {"value": 20}, {"value": 30} ],
     "B": [ {"value": 50}, {"value": 60}, {"value": 1000} ],
     "C": [ {"value": 30}, {"value": 90}, {"value": 300} ],
     }

var maxvalue = _.reduce(_.map(d,(items)=>{  
    return _.reduce(items , (p,i)=>{
            return p> i.value ? p: i.value;
        },0)
}) , (maxy, iter)=>{
    return maxy > iter ? maxy: iter;
},0);
```